# How to add a custom css selector to just a span??

Tags: css

I'm a real newbie so the wording to my question may not be accurate. I'm using wordpress and have a title that I want to be able to target with CSS. Here is the specific section I'm trying to target:

`<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"> Your Store, Your Way!</span></p>`

Here is a summary of the code (not really code):

```
[shortcode]
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"> Your Store, Your Way!</span></p>

[shortcode]
Text, blah blah blah blah blah`
```

So basically what can i add to this so that only the above mentioned span will be targeted? 
I don't have a live site right now, on a local install, sorry.

Thank you!!

Comment: make a class which has the design => `.span_class{ /* styles*/}` and then assign it `<span class="span_class"> </span>`

Comment: Thank you, both of you (NoobEditor & Era!) worked perfectly!

Comment: no probs mate...but please do some homework before asking next time!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give a class to `<span>` like:

```
<span class="className"> text text </span>
```

then write on CSS for it :

```
.className {
 color: red;
}
```

**OR**

You can give class to `<p>` tag like :

`<p class="className"><span>text text</span></p>`

then in CSS:

```
.className span {
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: strong suggestion.....even if 2 people know the answer....repetition should be avoided....coz it fails the purpose of SO!! :)

Comment: could be.. but I started writing before you I think.. :)

Comment: :D .. fair enough.. I will try to take a look on comments before posting my answers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question...
If you want to change span css elements which is located in 'p', incase not able to add class name to 'p'. You can write like the below attribute styles in css.

```
p[style="text-align:center"] span{
border:1px solid red
}
```

Comment: not recommended.....this will take all `p[style="text-align:center"]` into consideration for styling...your thoughts!!!!?? :)

Comment: Yes you are right. But we have to take atleast one parent class otherwise as you said it applies to entire application